# Remove Arraylist LIBGDX

Tags: java

```
private List<LadrilloVERDEEntity>LadrilloVERDElist = new ArrayList<LadrilloVERDEEntity>();

LadrilloVERDElist.add(new LadrilloVERDEEntity(world, ladriVerdeTexture,10,3));
LadrilloVERDElist.remove(1);     // ')' EXPECTED ERROR
```

//I need to remove the first object//

Comment: Remember that Java start to count from 0, not 1

Answer (score 0):

To remove the first object you need to remove the item of index 0. The computer starts counting from 0. Zero is always (in computer languages) the first one.

```
LadrilloVERDElist.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java uses zero based indexes.

Indexes start from 0 to N-1 where N is `size()` of list.

Example: The tenth element in a list is at index 9.

To remove the first object we use the index zero: `LadrilloVERDElist.remove(0);`